# Including JAR within a JAR makes class don't see jar content

Tags: java, jar

I'm merging jar files and one main class into one jar. The problem is that my main class use those jars, and if it's in one jar it just throws it cannot find classes definitions. How to make class see jars in jar?

Answer (score 1):

The Java `Launcher$AppClassLoader` does not know how to load classes from a Jar inside a Jar. What you need is a custom classloader that knows how to load classes and resources from a jars inside an archive, instead of from jars in the filesystem.

You can take a look on [one-jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/), it lets you package a Java application together with its dependency Jars into a single executable Jar file.

[JarClassLoader](http://www.jdotsoft.com/JarClassLoader.php) can also load classes, native libraries and resources from the top JAR and from JARs inside the top JAR.

Another solution (The very ugly one) would be to explode JAR contents inside your jar.

Comment: The very ugly solution also has the potential to mess things up if you overwrite files in `META-INF` folders. It's not a common issue but it depends on the libraries used and requires inspecting them manually.